# How to use labels c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, label

```
double dblSquare;
double strlbl;
double sum;

dblSquare = double.Parse(txtSquare.Text);

sum = "the square of" dblSquare "is" dblSquare* dblSquare;

strlbl = sum;
```

How would I get this to work so that I can have the label say "the square of (what ever number is entered) is (the square of what ever number is entered)"

Comment: You're assigning strings to a double value, not using proper string concatentation, then assigning that "string" to another double.

Comment: so how do I fix this

Comment: See my answer Mathew and please set the value to the label.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly to assign value in string variable like this

```
strlbl = "the square of"+ dblSquare+ "is"+ dblSquare* dblSquare;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do [string concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) like below:

```
string strResult = "the square of " + dblSquare + " is " + dblSquare * dblSquare;
```

then

```
yourlabel.Text = strResult;
```

> Concatenation is the process of appending one string to the end of
>   another string. When you concatenate string literals or string
>   constants by using the + operator, the compiler creates a single
>   string. No run time concatenation occurs. However, string variables
>   can be concatenated only at run time. In this case, you should
>   understand the performance implications of the various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` for concatenation.

Set the value of the label as:

```
strlbl.Text = "The square of " + dblSquare + " is " + (dblSquare * dblSquare);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strlbl = string.Format("the square of {0} is {1}.", dblSquare, dblSquare * dblSquare);
```